# In non-equilibrium energy calculations, how do you handle negative formation enthalpies?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, simulations, plasma-physics, non-equilibrium

I'm working on some simulation software at the moment which deals with high speed flows in chemical non-equilibrium (including plasma states).  When the code initially calculates total energy, it uses the following expression:

$E_{\infty} = \frac{1}{2} (\rho_{\infty} - \rho_{e})U^2 + \rho_{\infty} C_{v_{t}} T_{\infty} + \sum^s \left( \rho_s h_{0_{s}} \right)$

Where $U$ is velocity, $\rho_e$ is the electron density (which is 0 at the start of the simulation), $C_{v_{t}}$ is the translational specific heat of the mixture, $\rho_s$ and $h_{0_{s}}$ are the partial density and formation enthalpy of each chemical species respectively, and $\rho_{\infty}$ and $T_{\infty}$ are the total density and translational temperature of the mixture.

This expression is rearranged later after some flux calculations in order to calculate $T_{\infty}$ for the next iteration.

**My problem arises when I try to simulate entry into the Martian atmosphere (which is mostly $CO_2$ with a small amount of $N_2$).  This seems to occur because of the formation enthalpy, $h_0$, of $CO$ and $CO_2$ being negative.  When using the above expression, the last term turns the internal energy negative, which would then result in a negative $T_{\infty}$ at later stages of the calculation.  Does anyone know how to deal with this issue, or if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here?  (Apologies if my understanding is sub-par – I'm still quite new to this branch of physics)**

Comment: What is translational heat capacity and temperature?

Comment: @ChetMiller As far as I currently understand, translational terms like these refer to the motion of atoms, molecules, etc. without considering their rotational momentum, vibration within molecules, electronic state transitions, or free electrons.  So, only the energy mode involved with them moving around and colliding with other substances in some system.  The total energy is then the sum of the energies in all of these different modes (translational, rotational, vibrational, electronic, electrons).

Comment: @ChetMiller The Wikipedia article on this subject has been very helpful for me in the past https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_temperature

Comment: I know what temperature is.  What I meant was "what is translational temperature."

Comment: What is the reference state for zero internal energy?  Is $T_{\infty}$ some sort of free-stream velocity?

Comment: @ChetMiller Ah, I see sorry my mistake.  Yes, $T_{\infty}$ is a freestream temperature.  The initialisation values are $U_{\infty}=3006$ $m/s$, $T_{\infty}=189$ $K$, $C_{v_{t}}=479.35$ $J/kgK$, $\rho_e=0$ $kg/m^3$, $\rho_{\infty}=1.2728  \times 10^{-3}$ $kg/m^3$.
The partial densities of the components gases are $\rho_{CO_2}= 1.24 \times 10^{-3}$ $kg/m^3$ and $\rho_{N_2}= 3.28 \times 10^{-5}$ $kg/m^3$.  The formation enthalpies I have for these species are $h_{0_{CO2}}= 0$ $J/kgK$ and $h_{0_{N2}}= -8.934 \times 10^6$ $J/kgK$

Comment: You must have the heats of formation of the two gases switched.  Also, the internal energy reference state is not specified, so there is no reason why E in this calculation can't be negative.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, the N2 and CO2 formation enthalpies are reversed. As far as I know, we're just assuming that 0 J/kg internal energy is equal to 0 K translational temperature. How would that alter how we consider the formation enthalpies in the energy equation?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by this

Comment: We calculate total energy at the beginning of a simulation using the energy equation in my original question, and because we're mostly modelling CO2 and it has a negative formation enthalpy, the resulting energy is also negative. Later on in the calculation, the energy is adjusted by various other functions, and we try to rearrange the equation to find translational temperature. But because the energy is still very much negative, it results in negative temperature, which should be impossible if we assume that 0K corresponds to 0 total energy. My question is how do we deal with this issue.